# How to get remainder in javascript without using modulus

Tags: javascript

I'm having some issues with this code. The online applet I'm using is telling me that when it's expecting 1, it's actually getting -2 and it's saying I'm wrong. To me the code looks correct. Does anyone see something wrong here?

This is what I have so far:

```
function modulo(num1, num2) {
  if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)){
      return NaN;
  }
  if(num1 === 0){
      return 0;
  }
  if(num2 === 0){
      return NaN;
  }

  var quot = num1 - Math.floor(num1/num2)*num2;

  if(num1 < 0){
      return -(quot);
  }
  else{
      return quot;
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with just using the modulus operator? That's what it's for. There is no practical reason to avoid it. It is supported by all JavaScript implementations, and it's faster than using floating point.

Comment: The point of the exercise is to not use the modulus operator. Thats why I asked how to do it without the modulus operator.

Comment: What is an example of input values (params) that produce the problem?

Comment: @jmargolisvt Unfortunately repl.it doesn't tell me what it uses for examples, it just tells me what it expects given a scenario. In my code, it gives me errors on "should return neg number when first number is negative (expected -2 to be -1)" and "should return a positive number when the second number is negative (expected -2 to be 1)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **Math.abs** at some point:

```
function modulo(num1, num2) {
     if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)){
                              return NaN;
                            }
     if(num1 === 0){
            return 0;
            }
     if(num2 === 0){
            return NaN;
     }


       var newNum1 = Math.abs(num1);
       var newNum2 = Math.abs(num2);

       var quot = newNum1 - Math.floor( newNum1 / newNum2 ) * newNum2 ;

       if(num1 < 0){
             return -(quot);
       }
       else{
             return quot;
       }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you sir this did it for me.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Note your `modulo(-0, 1)` returns `0` but `-0 % 1` is `-0`. Your `modulo(1, Infinity)` returns `NaN` but `1 % Infinity` is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Fixed some things

```js
function divide() { 

var number = Number(document.getElementById('number').value);

var divide = Number(document.getElementById('divide').value);
 
var number2 = Number(Math.floor(number/divide));

var remainder = Number(number - (number2 * divide));

var result = remainder;

document.getElementById('quotient').innerHTML = "Quotient : " + number2;

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Remainder : " + result;

}
```

```html
<label>Number: </label><input type="number" id="number">

<label>Divisor: </label><input type="number" id="divide">

<div id="quotient">Quotient: </div>

<div id="result">Remainder: </div>

<button onclick="divide()">Divide</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with your return statement. It should have been `return quot - num2` when `num1` is less than 0.

I made it work and passes the several tests in the JSBin: http://jsbin.com/rufumi/3/edit?js,console

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is compliant with ECMAScript's definition of the [modulus operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-applying-the-mod-operator).

```
function modulo(num1, num2) {
  num1 = +num1;
  num2 = +num2;
  if (!num2 || !Number.isFinite(num1)) return NaN;
  if (!num1 || !Number.isFinite(num2)) return num1;
  return num1 - Math.trunc(num1/num2)*num2;
}
```